# How to launch a container instance with Boto in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, containers, boto3

I see in the AWS Boto3 documentation for ECS that we can create a cluster and then a service [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.create_service) but I do not see how to launch a container instance with this client. Do we need to create an EC2 instance first?

Answer (score 1):

I see now that the [register_container_instance](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.register_container_instance) method is what I am looking for. First one must create a EC2 instance with all the glorious networks, security groups, and keys etc and then call register_container_instance. EC2 docs are here [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#ec2)

Comment: I was wrong. That register_container_instance is "private", not to be used by users only the ECS agents. It requires a bunch of info as parameters. I did though find a dirty way to do it [here](https://bcb.github.io/aws/ecs) Essentially you need to populate /etc/ecs/ecs.config on the with ECS_CLUSTER=my-cluster on the EC2 instances. Using the user-data parameter.